# JavaScript highcharts: how to have two xAxis categories?

Tags: javascript, html, json, highcharts

I have a JavaScript array that looks like this:

```
$scope.myArray = [
(6, '03/02/2016', '10'),
(1, '03/02/2016', '12'),
(1, '03/02/2016', '12'),
(1, '03/02/2016', '12'),
(3, '03/02/2016', '13'),
(1, '03/02/2016', '13'),
(1, '03/02/2016', '14'),
(1, '03/02/2016', '15'),
(2, '03/03/2016', '15'),
(2, '03/08/2016', '09'),
(1, '03/09/2016', '02')];
```

So the first number in the list is the `id`, the second number id `date` and the third number is `time` (in 24HR format)

Now I am able to display a graph with `date` on `xAxis` and the `id` in the `series`.

This is what my graph looks like:

[image: This is what I have so far]

But I want it to look like this (Excel):
[image: This is what I want it to look like]

As shown in graph, I want to group the dates and display the `id` by time. How can I do that using javascript and highcharts? Thank you :)

PS: I don't know if you are interested in seeing my JavaScript code or not. I can post it if you want, just leave a comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `Grouped Categories` plugin for Highcharts. Manipulate your data for `Highcharts.xAxis` and you are good to go.

Site: [Plugin](https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories), [Demo](http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/)